# iPhone: Is the Application Directory length same in all cases?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I would like to know whether Application Directory path shown below, remains constant in terms of number of characters:

var/Mobile/D713AFE6-D6B3-4D1E-A1B9-28FD679FD124/Documents/apple.jpg

In above case, will

> D713AFE6-D6B3-4D1E-A1B9-28FD679FD124

remain constant in terms of length in all versions of iPhone SDK?

Please let me know.

Comment: application directory path wil be constant in case of number of characters

Comment: Why is this relevant? You should **never** rely on something being constant outside of the sandbox... unless you're doing jailbroken development, I guess. Either way, you can always call `[NSBundle mainBundle]` to get the path of the app's folder.

Comment: It is impossible for someone to say whether future versions of the iOS SDK will maintain this particular implementation detail.

Comment: Actually why is this required? For what reason why is this important whether it is constant or variable..

Comment: Is there a specific requirement where in you need to keep track of how many characters it is of? Or you are using it somewhere in your approach?

Comment: We are updating one of the app and we want to update absolute path with relative path.

Comment: Absolute Path with relative Path in what sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The app directory name does seem to have constant length, but relying on that is surely a bad idea. The length could easily change or even become variable with a new version of the OS.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the length is similar.

However you should verify it programmatically using last path component of NSString.